# Same Shortcode is used by a plugin and Wordpress.com feature

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am using Shortcodes for Quiz offered by wordpress.com ([link](https://en.support.wordpress.com/quiz-shortcode/)) which allows me to add a question followed by options. The question is nested between `[question][\question]` tags.

Everything works fine till I activate the AnsPress plugin. If activated, the question stem disappears and only options remain. The plugin uses a shortcode `[question]`, which I guess conflicts with a WP.com feature.

What is the way out (sorry I am not a programmer just getting my hands dirty attempting a DIY as hobbyist). I have reproduced the shortcode registration by the plugin below.

```html
public static function init_actions() {
  // Register question shortcode.
  add_shortcode( 'question', array( AnsPress_Question_Shortcode::get_instance(), 'anspress_question_sc' ) );
 }
```

I am attaching the images for you to better understand the issue I am facing.

With plugin deactivated:

[image: With plugin deactivated]

With plugin activated:

[image: With plugin activated]

Comment: To be clear, you're building a quiz, and you're using multiple plugins to try to produce it, and suspect the plugins are conflicting. Is there a reason for using multiple plugins? Have you confirmed working quiz experiences with both plugins independent of each other, ie have one plugin disabled while you test the other?

Comment: Sorry, if I could not put it clearly. The WP Shortcodes are for Quiz, building a quiz in posts/pages. The AnsPress plugin is a Q&A plugin, where visitors ask questions and members reply, something similar to this stack overflow.